# xamarin.android notification do not appear

Tags: c#, notifications, xamarin.android

I am trying to make a simple notification but it is not working so far. I have a simple app with just one button and when I click the button I want to push  a notification.

Here is my click event:

```
private void Notificate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        PendingIntent resultPending = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);


        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetContentIntent(resultPending)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.notification_icon_background)
            .SetContentTitle("Notification title")
            .SetContentText("My notification text");

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
        manager.Notify(100, builder.Build());
    }
```

I read that notifications might be turned off but I checked with `NotificationManagerCompat.From(this).AreNotificationsEnabled()` and it says they are ON. I don't get any errors also.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you do it something like this :

- Declare a pending intent (This intent gets fired on notification click)

  ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainAcitivity)); //Activity you want to open
   intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
   var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, RandomGenerator(), intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
  ```
- In case you want default sounds :

  ```
  Notification notify = new Notification();
  notify.Defaults = NotificationDefaults.Sound;
  notify.Defaults = NotificationDefaults.Vibrate;
  ```
- Use the NotificationCompat to push the notification (For backward Compatibility)

  ```
  NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
       .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
       .SetContentTitle(messageTitle)
       .SetContentText(messageBody)
       .SetSound(Settings.System.DefaultNotificationUri)
       .SetVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000 })
       .SetLights(Color.AliceBlue, 3000, 3000)
       .SetAutoCancel(true)
       .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
  ```
- In your MainActivity create a notification channel

  ```
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
          {
              String channelId = Context.GetString(Resource.String.default_notification_channel_id);
              NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, MessageTitle, NotificationImportance.Default);
              channel.Description=(MessageBody);
              builder.SetChannelId(channelId);
          }
  ```
- Then notifying the system that a notification is thrown from your application:

  ```
     NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);                             
     notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
     notificationManager.Notify(RandomGenerator(), notificationBuilder.Build());
  ```
- Also, Random numbers so that the notifications don't switch places when a new one is thrown :

  ```
  private int RandomGenerator() 
  {
     return new Random().Next( int.MinValue, int.MaxValue );
  }
  ```
- And for Android Oreo channel compatibility as you can see [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest), you need to add the following metadata element in your `AndroidManifest.xml` within the application component:

  ```
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
  android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
  ```
- This default channel will be used when notification message has no specified channel, or if the channel provided has not yet been created by the app.

Comment: when I add code to `AndroidManifest.xml` I get `No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@string/default_notification_channel_id').`

Comment: Its because you need to create that it's not built in just give it a channel id something like this in your striings.xml: `<string name="default_notification_channel_id" translatable="false">fcm_default_channel</string>`

Comment: Also i have made a little changes for channels for andorid Oreo kindly check that and revert in case something doesn't work or in case of any queries

Comment: it says that there is no function like `.CreateNotificationChannel()`

Comment: also do I need channels when I want to make a local notification?

Comment: Just use NotificationManager instead of NotificaitonManagerCompat

Comment: I want to ask a quick question, tho. What is the meaning of the `MessageTitle` and `MessageBody` in the if statement, when I already have them in the notification title and context?

Comment: The MessageTitle and MessageBody later are for the channel, so that the channel has message info, secondly the if statement is to check if the device has Android Oreo or not if not then the channel is not required makes sense?

Comment: Also, the line `Settings.System.DefaultNotificationUri` complains that `Settings` doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: And the line `NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);` generates the error `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Context.GetSystemService(String)'`.  So, no this does not work.

Comment: Changing that line to:
`NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);` got it to work.

Comment: @PrescottChartier Actually, the code here is sort of not copy paste, you need to make your own changes as per your conditions and requirements

Comment: @G.hakim Understood, sorry if I'm a little focused on my situation.  This post actually helped me to get my service notification working, I was just posting the code that worked in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this: as per microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications)

```
private void ThrowNotification(string CHANNEL_ID)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));

        // Create a PendingIntent; we're only using one PendingIntent (ID = 0):
        const int pendingIntentId = 0;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, pendingIntentId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        // Instantiate the builder and set notification elements, including pending intent:
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .SetContentTitle("Sample Notification")
            .SetContentText("Hello World! This is my first action notification!")
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_mtrl_checked_circle);

        // Build the notification:
        Notification notification = builder.Build();

        // Get the notification manager:
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
            GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

        // Publish the notification:
        const int notificationId = 0;
        notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);
    }
```

it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to nuget package manager in visual studio and install Plugin.LocalNotification The nuget link below gives instructions on how to use the package, there is no point in me redocumenting that here. Also, the video link shows how to use the nuget package.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Nj_TRPlx-8

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.LocalNotification

Comment: Michael Hamilton, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)